# NAV to CRM Dynamics connector mapping issue in NAV sales order to CRM order

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, navision

I am working on Microsoft connector mapping NAV 2016 to CRM 2016. I am facing issue while doing mapping of NAV sales order to CRM order. I have googled but didn't find anything. Looking for solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Image is attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The message is indicating that you are missing a unit in CRM. You should run the map for mapping Unit Schedules and Unit Groups (which should also be listed in the manual before the map for integrating sales orders). This will transfer the needed units from NAV to your product catalog in CRM.

As a side-note, the *Connector for Microsoft Dynamics* has been deprecated (and has never been a great product). [Move to something else](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dynamicsconnector/2016/04/08/connector-for-microsoft-dynamics-support-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-beyond-dynamics-crm-version-2016/):

> Dynamics NAV 2016 includes a new interoperability framework for
>   connecting with Dynamics CRM 2015 (7.x.x.x) and successor versions. 
>   We recommend existing Dynamics NAV connections to Dynamics CRM
>   versions greater than 2015 transition to this new framework once the
>   Dynamics NAV instance is updated to Dynamics NAV 2016 or beyond.  New
>   implementations of Dynamics NAV 2016 or beyond and Dynamics CRM 2015
>   or beyond should use the new NAV framework as well.

Comment: Would like to emphasize that the connector is a *terrible* tool and should be avoided at all costs. Look up KingsWaySoft's products for a superior replacement.

Comment: Definitely! Using the connector is painful, so Scribe/KingswaySoft/something entirely different should be used instead.

Comment: Yep! I used to work for Scribe. Also a superior tool (a bit more expensive than the KingsWaySoft offerings but also more features). We have probably spoken before. :)